# react native push values to array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-native, object

I have a simple react-native. where I ma tracking user location and pushing that into array to draw a simple line.  but when I try to push values it give me this error

```
 TypeError: cannot add a new property, js engine: hermes
```

here is my code and I shared all the three case. I also tried many of the stackoverflow questions but none of this working. it was working 3 to 4 days earlier. it day 3 I am working on this but non of the case is working. sometime its start working but values or not pushing. means array is already empty. case 4 is the  only screen and it works fine

**CASE 1**

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {Alert, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, View} from 'react-native';
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';
import {moderateScale} from 'react-native-size-matters';
import Entypo from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';
import {MainRoutes} from '../constants/Routes';
import colors from '../constants/theme';
const GpsTrackerScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  let location_route = [];
  useEffect(() => {
    watchPosition();
  }, []);

  const watchPosition = () => {
    try {
      const watchID = Geolocation.watchPosition(
        position => {
          let coords = {
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          };

          location_route.push(coords);
        },
        error => Alert.alert('WatchPosition Error', JSON.stringify(error)),
      );
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert('WatchPosition Error', JSON.stringify(error));
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate(MainRoutes.TrackHistoryScreen)}
        style={styles.HistoryButton}>
        <Entypo name={'back-in-time'} color={'#fff'} size={moderateScale(30)} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default GpsTrackerScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {flex: 1, backgroundColor: colors.white, alignItems: 'center'},
  HistoryButton: {
    width: moderateScale(50),
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    zIndex: 200,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    height: moderateScale(50),
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal: moderateScale(10),
    alignItems: 'center',
    elevation: 5,
    borderRadius: moderateScale(50),
    backgroundColor: colors.primaryColor,
  },
});
```

**CASE 2:**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Alert, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, View} from 'react-native';
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';
import {moderateScale} from 'react-native-size-matters';
import Entypo from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';
import fonts from '../constants/fonts';
import {MainRoutes} from '../constants/Routes';
import {SCREEN_WIDTH} from '../constants/scaling';
import colors from '../constants/theme';
const GpsTrackerScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const [location_route, setLocationRoute] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    watchPosition();
  }, []);

  const watchPosition = () => {
    try {
      const watchID = Geolocation.watchPosition(
        position => {
          let coords = {
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          };

          let temp_route = [...location_route];
          temp_route.push(coords);

          setLocationRoute(temp_route);
        },
        error => Alert.alert('WatchPosition Error', JSON.stringify(error)),
      );
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert('WatchPosition Error', JSON.stringify(error));
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate(MainRoutes.TrackHistoryScreen)}
        style={styles.HistoryButton}>
        <Entypo name={'back-in-time'} color={'#fff'} size={moderateScale(30)} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default GpsTrackerScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {flex: 1, backgroundColor: colors.white, alignItems: 'center'},
  HistoryButton: {
    width: moderateScale(50),
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    zIndex: 200,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    height: moderateScale(50),
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal: moderateScale(10),
    alignItems: 'center',
    elevation: 5,
    borderRadius: moderateScale(50),
    backgroundColor: colors.primaryColor,
  },
});
```

**CASE 3:**

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {Alert, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, View} from 'react-native';
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';
import {moderateScale} from 'react-native-size-matters';
import Entypo from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';
import {MainRoutes} from '../constants/Routes';
import colors from '../constants/theme';

let location_route = [];
const GpsTrackerScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    watchPosition();
  }, []);

  const watchPosition = () => {
    try {
      const watchID = Geolocation.watchPosition(
        position => {
          let coords = {
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          };

          location_route.push(coords);
        },
        error => Alert.alert('WatchPosition Error', JSON.stringify(error)),
      );
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert('WatchPosition Error', JSON.stringify(error));
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate(MainRoutes.TrackHistoryScreen)}
        style={styles.HistoryButton}>
        <Entypo name={'back-in-time'} color={'#fff'} size={moderateScale(30)} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default GpsTrackerScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {flex: 1, backgroundColor: colors.white, alignItems: 'center'},
  HistoryButton: {
    width: moderateScale(50),
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    zIndex: 200,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    height: moderateScale(50),
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal: moderateScale(10),
    alignItems: 'center',
    elevation: 5,
    borderRadius: moderateScale(50),
    backgroundColor: colors.primaryColor,
  },
});
```

**CASE 4:**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Alert, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, View} from 'react-native';
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';
import {moderateScale} from 'react-native-size-matters';
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';
import Entypo from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';
const GpsTrackerScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  let location_route = [];
  const [watchid, setWatchId] = useState(null);
  SplashScreen.hide();
  const clearwatch = () => {
    Geolocation.clearWatch(watchid);
  };
  const watchPosition = () => {
    try {
      const watchID = Geolocation.watchPosition(
        position => {
          let coords = {
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          };

          location_route.push(coords);
          console.log(location_route, 'location_route');
        },
        error => Alert.alert('WatchPosition Error', JSON.stringify(error)),
        {
          accuracy: {
            android: 'high',
            ios: 'best',
          },
          enableHighAccuracy: false,
          timeout: 15000,
          maximumAge: 10000,
          distanceFilter: 0,
          forceRequestLocation: true,
          forceLocationManager: true,
          showLocationDialog: true,
        },
      );
      setWatchId(watchID);
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert('WatchPosition Error', JSON.stringify(error));
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => watchPosition()}
        style={styles.HistoryButton}>
        <Entypo name={'back-in-time'} color={'#fff'} size={moderateScale(30)} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => clearwatch()}
        style={styles.HistoryButton}>
        <Entypo name={'back-in-time'} color={'#fff'} size={moderateScale(30)} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default GpsTrackerScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff', alignItems: 'center'},
  HistoryButton: {
    width: moderateScale(50),

    zIndex: 200,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    height: moderateScale(50),
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal: moderateScale(10),
    alignItems: 'center',
    elevation: 5,
    margin: 100,
    borderRadius: moderateScale(50),
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  },
});
```